# Hough transform to detect and delete lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to use the **Hough transform** to detect lines in my image.But instead of plotting the lines I want to delete each line detected in my original image.

```
image=imread('image.jpg');
image = im2bw(image);
BW=edge(image,'canny');
imshow(BW);
figure,imshow(BW);
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
P  = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
```

Now after this I have got all the lines. But I want to delete all these lines from my original image, **keeping rest of the image as before**. Is there some way I can do this?

**Edit** I am uploading an image.I want to delete all the lines and keep the circular part.This is just an example image.Basically my objective is to delete the line segments and keep rest of the image
[image]

Comment: please post an example image. what do you mean by "deleting" a line?

Comment: Why can't you just invert the values of your lines so that the lines become `0` and everything else `1`. This gives you a mask. Multiply the mask with your image and your have removed your lines. If you want to fill the gaps left by the lines you just removed, then that is a different question.

Comment: @kkuilla Yes but for that I need to locate the pixels of the line segments.I dont want to fill the lines just remove them one by one.

Comment: @Shai I have editted my question and added an example image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is that your lines are thicker than one pixel. 
The lines from the hough transform seem to be one pixel thick and
that doesn't help.

I propose that you delete the lines that you get from the Hough transform first.
This will sort of divide the hockey rink of whatever it is into segments
that will be easier to process.

Then you label each segment with **[`bwlabel`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html)**. For each object, find the 
endpoints and fit a line between the endpoints. If the line and the object
have more pixels in common than a certain threshold, then we say that the object 
is a line and we delete it from the image.

You may have to play around with the Hough transform's threshold value.

This technique has some flaws though. It will delete a filled square, 
rectangle or circle but you haven't got any of those so you should be ok.

#### Results

[image][image]

---

#### Explanation

This is your code that I modified a bit. I removed the gradient because it
it easier to work with solid objects. The gradient gave very thin lines.
I also work on the complement image because the bw functions work with 1 
as forgound rather than 0 as in your original image.

```
org_image_bw=im2bw(double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcphc.png')));
image = imcomplement(org_image_bw);
[H,T,R] = hough(image);
P  = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.27*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(image,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
```

Loop through the lines you have got and delete them

```
processed_image = image;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];

    % // Use the question of a line y = kx + m to calulate x,y

    % // Calculate the maximum number of elements in a line
   numOfElems = max(max(xy(:,1))-min(xy(:,1)),max(xy(:,2))-min(xy(:,2)) ) ;

   % // Cater for the special case where the equation of a line is
   % // undefined, i.e. there is only one x value.
   % // We use linspace rather than the colon operator because we want
   % // x and y to have the same length and be evenly spaced.
   if (diff(xy(:,1)) == 0)           
       y = round(linspace(min(xy(:,2)),max(xy(:,2)),numOfElems));
       x = round(linspace(min(xy(:,1)),max(xy(:,1)),numOfElems));      
   else

       k = diff(xy(:,2)) ./ diff(xy(:,1)); % // the slope
       m = xy(1,2) - k.*xy(1,1); % // The crossing of the y-axis

       x = round(linspace(min(xy(:,1)), max(xy(:,1)), numOfElems));
       y = round(k.*x + m); % // the equation of a line
   end

   processed_image(y,x) = 0; % // delete the line
end
```

This is what the image looks after we have deleted the detected lines. Please note that the original hockey rink and been divided into multiple objects.

[image]

Label the remaining objects

```
L = bwlabel(processed_image);
```

Run through each object and find the end points.
Then fit a line to it. If, let's say 80% the fitted line covers
the object, then it is a line.

A fitted line could look like this. The diagonal blue line represents the fitted line and covers most of 
the object (the white area). We therefore say that the object is a line.

[image]

```
% // Set the threshold
th = 0.8;

% // Loop through the objects
for objNr=1:max(L(:))
   [objy, objx] = find(L==objNr);

   % Find the end points
   endpoints = [min(objx) min(objy) ...
       ;max(objx) max(objy)];

   % Fit a line to it. y = kx + m
   numOfElems = max(max(endpoints(:,1))-min(endpoints(:,1)),max(endpoints(:,2))-min(endpoints(:,2)) ) ;

   % // Cater for the special case where the equation of a line is
   % // undefined, i.e. there is only one x value
   if (diff(endpoints(:,1)) == 0)           
       y = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,2)),max(endpoints(:,2)),numOfElems));
       x = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,1)),max(endpoints(:,1)),numOfElems));      
   else
       k = diff(endpoints(:,2)) ./ diff(endpoints(:,1)); % the slope
       m = endpoints(1,2) - k.*endpoints(1,1); % The crossing of the y-axis           
       x = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,1)), max(endpoints(:,1)), numOfElems));

       y = round(k.*x + m);
       % // Set any out of boundary items to the boundary
       y(y>size(L,1)) = size(L,1);
   end

   % // Convert x and y to an index for easy comparison with the image
   % // We sort them so that we are comparing the same pixels
   fittedInd = sort(sub2ind(size(L),y,x)).';
   objInd = sort(sub2ind(size(L),objy,objx));

   % // Calculate the similarity. Intersect returns unique entities so we
   % // use unique on fittedInd
   fitrate = numel(intersect(fittedInd,objInd)) ./ numel(unique(fittedInd));
   if (fitrate >= th)
       L(objInd) = 0;
       processed_image(objInd) = 0;
       % // figure(1),imshow(processed_image)
   end       
end
```

Display the result

```
figure,imshow(image);title('Original');
figure,imshow(processed_image);title('Processed image');
```

---

#### Complete example

```
org_image_bw=im2bw(double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcphc.png')));
image = imcomplement(org_image_bw);

[H,T,R] = hough(image);
P  = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.27*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(image,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);

processed_image = image;
    for k = 1:length(lines)
       xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];

        % // Use the question of a line y = kx + m to calulate x,y

        %Calculate the maximum number of elements in a line
        numOfElems = max(max(xy(:,1))-min(xy(:,1)),max(xy(:,2))-min(xy(:,2)) ) ;

       % // Cater for the special case where the equation of a line is
       % // undefined, i.e. there is only one x value.
       % // We use linspace rather than the colon operator because we want
       % // x and y to have the same length and be evenly spaced.
       if (diff(xy(:,1)) == 0)           
           y = round(linspace(min(xy(:,2)),max(xy(:,2)),numOfElems));
           x = round(linspace(min(xy(:,1)),max(xy(:,1)),numOfElems));      
       else

           k = diff(xy(:,2)) ./ diff(xy(:,1)); % the slope
           m = xy(1,2) - k.*xy(1,1); % The crossing of the y-axis

           x = round(linspace(min(xy(:,1)), max(xy(:,1)), numOfElems));
           y = round(k.*x + m); % // the equation of a line
       end

       processed_image(y,x) = 0; % // delete the line
    end


    % // Label the remaining objects
    L = bwlabel(processed_image);

    % // Run through each object and find the end points.
    % // Then fit a line to it. If, let's say 80% the fitted line covers
    % // the object, then it is a line.

    % // Set the threshold
    th = 0.8;

    % // Loop through the objects
    for objNr=1:max(L(:))
       [objy, objx] = find(L==objNr);

       % Find the end points
       endpoints = [min(objx) min(objy) ...
           ;max(objx) max(objy)];

       % Fit a line to it. y = kx + m
       numOfElems = max(max(endpoints(:,1))-min(endpoints(:,1)),max(endpoints(:,2))-min(endpoints(:,2)) ) ;

       % Cater for the special case where the equation of a line is
       % undefined, i.e. there is only one x value
       if (diff(endpoints(:,1)) == 0)           
           y = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,2)),max(endpoints(:,2)),numOfElems));
           x = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,1)),max(endpoints(:,1)),numOfElems));      
       else
           k = diff(endpoints(:,2)) ./ diff(endpoints(:,1)); % the slope
           m = endpoints(1,2) - k.*endpoints(1,1); % The crossing of the y-axis           
           x = round(linspace(min(endpoints(:,1)), max(endpoints(:,1)), numOfElems));

           y = round(k.*x + m);
           % // Set any out of boundary items to the boundary
           y(y>size(L,1)) = size(L,1);
       end

       % // Convert x and y to an index for easy comparison with the image
       % // We sort them so that we are comparing the same pixels
       fittedInd = sort(sub2ind(size(L),y,x)).';
       objInd = sort(sub2ind(size(L),objy,objx));

       % Calculate the similarity. Intersect returns unique entities so we
       % use unique on fittedInd
       fitrate = numel(intersect(fittedInd,objInd)) ./ numel(unique(fittedInd));
       if (fitrate >= th)
           L(objInd) = 0;
           processed_image(objInd) = 0;
           % // figure(1),imshow(processed_image)
       end       
    end

   % // Display the result 
   figure,imshow(image);title('Original');
   figure,imshow(processed_image);title('Processed image');
```

Comment: As I said,that will work in this image.But if I had another object say a circle then this will not work

Comment: But then you have changed your question. Your question is specifically about lines. Not circles.

Comment: Yes I want to delete line segments keeping rest of the image as before.This was my original question and my question still remains the same.I want to just delete line segments and keep rest of the image as before

Comment: @kkuilla I think your answer is not applicable here.This will remove all the objects from the image.But I think OP  wants to remove only the lines.

Comment: @Noober No, it will only remove the lines that have been detected by the Hough transform. That is the purpose of the mask. The lines in the mask are `0` and and everything else `1`. The lines only (the zeros) will be removed when multiplying the mask with the original image and everything else will remain ( the ones).

Comment: @kkuilla In your first line what image are you using.

Comment: @kkuilla This is giving me following error-
Error in graythresh 
validateattributes(I,{'uint8','uint16','double','single','int16'},{'nonsparse'}, ..

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure that your `lines` variable is a matrix and of correct type?

Comment: @Noober It referred to the image the OP posted originally. The question has changed and the image removed so I'll update it to reflect that. The `lines` variable refers to the `lines` variable in the question.

Comment: @kkuilla I am using the same `lines` variable which I have used in my code in my question above.But I am getting the same error as I mentioned before

Comment: I messed the arguments up. Apologies. See update. The principle with a mask holds though.

Comment: @kkuilla I am not sure but how can you use `lines` from hough transform.As far as I know,`graythresh` will take only matrix as an input and here `lines` as obtained from `hough` is not a matrix.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It all comes from the original question. The original question included an image with lines. That image was representative of the variable `lines`. However, the question has changed since and it might be that the image is not representative of `lines` anymore. That is something I don't know. The principles of a mask still holds though...

Comment: @kkuilla I again say you cannot use `lines` with graythresh.Please try running the entire code because I think this is bound to give error.I am going to run it myself.

Comment: @kkuilla I am not able to understand.The line with `greythresh` still gives me the same error.By `lines` do you mean my input image or what I get after doing Hough Transformation.

Comment: Ok. I'll get it. I am wrong. Apologies. Your original image confused me. The code will not work as such. `lines` is a struct. Not an image. Therefore you need to create an empty image (`mask`) and use the equation of a line to draw the lines onto the image. Invert the mask and multiply. Unfortunately, I haven't got the time to rectify it right now. I have to do it later. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use J. E. Bresenham's algorightm. It is implemented by A. Wetzler in the following [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m), which I tested myself.

The algorithm will give you the pixel coordinates of where the line would be, given that you will provide the start and end point of the line, which is already given in `lines` in your code above.

Here is the code I used, which uses the matlab function referenced above:

```
%This is your code above ========
image=imread('hcphc.png');
image = im2bw(image);
BW=edge(image,'canny');
imshow(BW);
figure,imshow(BW);
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
P  = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
% =========

% Proposed solution:

% This will work for as many lines as you detected

for k=1:length(lines)

    % Call Bresenham's algorithm
    [x, y] = bresenham(lines(k).point1(1), lines(k).point1(2), ...
                       lines(k).point2(1), lines(k).point2(2));

    % This is where you replace the line, here I use 0, but you can use
    % whatever you want. However, note that if you use BW, you should only
    % replace with 0 or 1, because is a logical image. If you want to use 
    % the original image, well, you know what to do.
    BW(y, x) = 0;

    % And now watch the lines disapear!  (you can remove this line)
    imagesc(BW), drawnow; pause(1);
end
```

Remember, download the [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m) first.