# How to remove horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to remove horizontal and vertical lines in a binary image. Is there any method for filtering these lines? `bwareaopen()` is not good method to remove these lines and also Dilation and Erosion are not good for these cases.
Does any one know a solution?

Example image:

[image: example]

EDIT:(added more example images:

http://s1.upload7.ir/downloads/pPqTDnmsmjHUGTEpbwnksf3uUkzncDwr/example%202.png

source file of images:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tamcdqk244ktoyp/AAAuxkmYgBkB8erNS9SajkGVa?dl=0

www.directexe.com/9cg/pics.rar

Comment: This might give you some ideas [Hough transform to detect and delete lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31158394/2545927). Please note that Hough transform is not a necessity to make the idea work. The idea is general.

Comment: thanks dear @kkuilla for your suggest, But hough transform is so slow to my job.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need Hough transform to implement the idea. The idea is that you fit a line to all your segments and delete the ones that are not a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `regionprops` and remove regions with high eccentricity (meaning the region is long and thin) and orientation near 0 or near 90 degrees (regions which are vertical or horizontal).

Code:

```
img = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('removelines.jpg')));

mask = ~im2bw(img);

rp = regionprops(mask, 'PixelIdxList', 'Eccentricity', 'Orientation');

% Get high eccentricity and orientations at 90 and 0 degrees
rp = rp([rp.Eccentricity] > 0.95 & (abs([rp.Orientation]) < 2 | abs([rp.Orientation]) > 88));

mask(vertcat(rp.PixelIdxList)) = false;

imshow(mask);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I followed the same approach. Works better than a morphology approach.

Comment: Dear @jucestain , I really appreciate you for what you have done for me. how can I change your code to remove the noise of these examples which I added to my question? PLZ look at examples and help me more..thanks alot.

Comment: @KaroAmini For that data set, can you consistently get the border fully around the letters and uncropped? If so, you should be able to detect the border by removing the region with a very large `BoundingBox` or `ConvexArea` quantity. Also, just FYI but there is a cool [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) that describes an approach to detect letters directly. This might help as well.

Comment: @KaroAmini Basically, you need to determine if you want to detect and remove nonletters *or* if you want to detect letters directly and remove everything else.

Comment: Dear @jucestain , Cuz of  variety of pics I can't crop the letters or borders. in this step I want to remove noises and the next step extract and read letters by the OCR, Actually the main goal is detect and extract the letters.

Answer (score 3):

If all of your images are the same where the horizontal and vertical lines are touching the border, a simple call to [`imclearborder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) will do the trick.  `imclearborder` removes any object pixels that are touching the borders of the image.  You'll need to invert the image so that the characters are white and the background is dark, then reinvert back, but I'm assuming that isn't an issue.  However, to be sure that none of the actual characters get removed because they may also be touching the border, it may be prudent to artificially pad the top border of the image with a single pixel thickness, clear the border, then recrop.

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1hUa.jpg'); %// Read image directly from StackOverflow

im = ~im2bw(im); %// Convert to black and white and invert
im_pad = zeros(size(im,1)+1, size(im,2)) == 1; %// Pad the image too with a single pixel border
im_pad(2:end,:) = im;

out = ~imclearborder(im_pad); %// Clear border pixels then reinvert
out = out(2:end,:); %// Crop out padded pixels

imshow(out); %// Show image
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir @rayryeng  you always helped me to solve my problems. I added more example images , how can I change your code to remove binary noise of these images?? I do appreciate for what you have done for me.

Comment: @KaroAmini - Those images are quite different than your original problem.  For one thing, there is a significant amount of noise.  I would have to reformulate my problem completely to accommodate for those images you have uploaded.

Comment: I uploaded the images individualy in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tamcdqk244ktoyp/AAAuxkmYgBkB8erNS9SajkGVa?dl=0 , I really appreciate you.

Comment: @KaroAmini - This unfortunately isn't a priority currently.  When I get around to it, I'll try and reformulate this problem to be more adaptive to your data.

Comment: It's kind of you. thank you indeed Dear sir @rayryeng

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly find the horizontal and vertical lines. Since, the edge map will also be binary so you can perform a logical subtraction operation in between the images. To find vertical lines, you can use (in MATLAB)

```
BW = edge(I,'sobel','vertical');
```

For horizontal lines, you can use

```
% Generate horizontal edge emphasis kernel
h = fspecial('sobel');

% invert kernel to detect vertical edges
h = h';

J = imfilter(I,h);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I doubt this works for fat lines, as the edge detectors are no line detectors. They find the transition between different shades of gray. So you will not remove the whole line, because inside the line does not change its color. Plus you will also detect any vertical or horizontal gradients along the letters, which do not want to touch.

Comment: This only finds **edges**, not lines.  However, this may possibly work if the line is a single pixel thick, but for lines of variable thickness, this would only detect the perimeter of the line.  In that case, I fail to see how this would work for this problem.